# Using randomForest package in R, how to get probabilities from classification model?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, predict

TL;DR :

***Is there something I can flag in the original*** `randomForest` ***call to avoid having to re-run the*** `predict` ***function to get predicted categorical probabilities, instead of just the likely category?***

Details:

I am using the [randomForest](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf) package.

I have a model something like:

```
model <- randomForest(x=out.data[train.rows, feature.cols],
                      y=out.data[train.rows, response.col],
                      xtest=out.data[test.rows, feature.cols],
                      ytest=out.data[test.rows, response.col],
                      importance= TRUE)
```

where `out.data` is a data frame, with `feature.cols` a mixture of numeric and categorical features, while `response.col` is a `TRUE` / `FALSE` binary variable, that I forced into `factor` so that `randomForest` model will properly treat it as categorical.

All runs well, and the variable `model` is returned to me properly.  However, I cannot seem to find a flag or parameter to pass to the `randomForest` function so that `model` is returned to me with the ***probabilities*** of `TRUE` or `FALSE`.  Instead, I get simply predicted values.  That is, if I look at `model$predicted`, I'll see something like:

```
FALSE
FALSE
TRUE
TRUE
FALSE
.
.
.
```

Instead, I want to see something like:

```
   FALSE  TRUE
1  0.84   0.16
2  0.66   0.34
3  0.11   0.89
4  0.17   0.83
5  0.92   0.08
.   .      .
.   .      .
.   .      .
```

I can get the above, but in order to do so, I need to do something like:

```
tmp <- predict(model, out.data[test.rows, feature.cols], "prob")
```

[`test.rows` captures the row numbers for those that were used during the model testing.  The details are not shown here, but are simple since the test row IDs are output into `model`.]

Then everything works fine.  The ***problem*** is that the model is big and takes a very long time to run, and even the prediction itself takes a while.  Since the prediction ***should*** be entirely unnecessary (I am simply looking to calculate the ROC curve on the test data set, the data set that should have already been calculated), I was hoping to skip this step.  ***Is there something I can flag in the original*** `randomForest` ***call to avoid having to re-run the*** `predict` ***function?***

Comment: The `randomForest` function can be used for any types of analysis; the question could benefit from a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that shows exactly what you are running with some sample/representative data. I would think if you just do `predict(model, type="prob")` it would be faster. Here, you want the prediction from the model you fit, so no need to pass in a `newdata=` parameter. But since you didn't provide any way to test, it's hard to say if this will solve your problem.

Comment: So you haven't noticed the votes component of the random forest object? There's a pretty clear description of it in the docs.

Comment: Thanks, @joran ... I thought that "votes" might simply mean the probability.  (E.g., if 300 / 500 trees that an obs. experienced voted "TRUE", then it would give 60% true.)  However, that did not seem statistically "tight", in that IID is assumed by proxy.  Since proximity and other data are available, I thought maybe more exacting probabilities could be extracted by adjusting the weights in some fashion.  I presume this is not done.  Thanks for confirmation!

Comment: Your comment makes me think that you should maybe spend some time reading some references on random forests, particularly maybe Breiman's original paper (reference in the pckg docs). As the docse for `votes` states, the proportions are for OOB (out of bag) votes, so each case is only run down a tree for which it was not in the bootstrap sample. The are some other subtleties to how the OOB error rate is calculated (see `oob.times`), but what is in `votes` is fairly rigorous...

Comment: ...there are some critiques of OOB error rates, but again I would recommend reading up on the RF literature on that topic.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`model$predicted` is **NOT** the same thing returned by `predict()`. If you want the probability of the `TRUE` or `FALSE` class then you must run `predict()`, or pass `x,y,xtest,ytest` like

```
randomForest(x,y,xtest=x,ytest=y),
```

where `x=out.data[, feature.cols], y=out.data[, response.col]`.

`model$predicted` returns the class based on which class had the larger value in `model$votes` for each record. `votes`, as @joran pointed out is the proportion of OOB(out of bag) ‘votes’ from the random forest, a vote only counting when the record was selected in an OOB sample. On the other hand `predict()` returns the true probability for each class based on votes by all the trees.

Using `randomForest(x,y,xtest=x,ytest=y)` functions a little differently than when passing a formula or simply `randomForest(x,y)`, as in the example given above. `randomForest(x,y,xtest=x,ytest=y)` WILL return the probability for each class, this may sound a little weird, but it is found under `model$test$votes`, and the predicted class under `model$test$predicted`, which simply selects the class based on which class had the larger value in `model$test$votes`. Also, when using `randomForest(x,y,xtest=x,ytest=y)`, `model$predicted` and `model$votes` have the same definition as above.

Finally, just to note, if `randomForest(x,y,xtest=x,ytest=y)` is used, then, in order to use predict() function the keep.forest flag should be set to TRUE.

```
model=randomForest(x,y,xtest=x,ytest=y,keep.forest=TRUE). 
prob=predict(model,x,type="prob")
```

`prob` **WILL** be equivalent to `model$test$votes` since the test data input are both `x`.

Comment: Hi Oscar, I did provide & have been providing the "test" data set.  Apologies I did not originally specify that... I have edited my original post.  Thanks for specifying it is under "$test$votes"... that is precisely what I was looking for, although it still seems to be making lots of assumptions, like IID.  (There is no covariance test or anything performed, as far as I can tell.)  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Mike, I'm glad you got it. Don't forget to set the `keep.forest=TRUE` if you want to use the `predict()` function, just in case you want to pass other test data points. I don't think that there is a covariance test, but I have not looked into it so I'm not sure.