# R caret: values of $finalModel$predicted and values obtained by predict()

Tags: r, prediction, r-caret

To illustrate the differences between `$finalModel$predicted` and the values computed by `predict()`, I set up the following code:

```
library(caret)
library(randomForest)

dat <- data.frame(target = c(2.5, 4.5, 6.1, 3.2, 2.2),
              A = c(1.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.7, 8.1),
              B = c(44.5, 50.1, 23.7, 89.2, 10.5),
              C = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B"))

control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3,     search="grid", savePred =T)

tunegrid <- expand.grid(.mtry=c(1:3))

set.seed(42)
rf_gridsearch <- train(target ~ A + B + C, 
                   data = dat, 
                   method="rf",
                   ntree = 2500, 
                   metric= "RMSE", 
                   tuneGrid=tunegrid, 
                   trControl=control)

dat$pred_caret <- rf_gridsearch$finalModel$predicted

dat$pred <- predict(object = rf_gridsearch, newdata = dat[,2:4])
dat$pred2 <- predict(object = rf_gridsearch$finalModel, newdata = dat[,2:4])
```

This last line of this code gives the error message

```
Error in predict.randomForest(object = rf_gridsearch$finalModel, 
newdata = dat[,  : variables in the training data missing in newdata
```

How is it possible to use `$finalModel` with predict?

Why does the data in column `dat$pred_caret` differ from `dat$pred`? What is the difference between the 2 predictions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There already are a lot of questions related to this issue. See

- [Using randomForest package in R, how to get probabilities from classification model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715502/using-randomforest-package-in-r-how-to-get-probabilities-from-classification-mo)
- [The Effect of Specifying Training Data as New Data when Making Random Forest Predictions in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594951/the-effect-of-specifying-training-data-as-new-data-when-making-random-forest-pre)
- [R random forest inconsistent predictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51865353/r-random-forest-inconsistent-predictions)
- [Error when using predict() on a randomForest object trained with caret's train() using formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097730/error-when-using-predict-on-a-randomforest-object-trained-with-carets-train)
- [Different results with randomForest() and caret's randomForest (method = "rf")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36696974/different-results-with-randomforest-and-carets-randomforest-method-rf)

on SO and [Question 1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298653/predict-values-from-random-forest-model), [Question 2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/290836/random-forest-predictions-in-r), [Question 3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141462/different-results-from-randomforest-via-caret-and-the-basic-randomforest-package), [Question 4](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81609/is-preprocessing-needed-before-prediction-using-finalmodel-of-randomforest-with), [Question 5](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188722/different-randomforest-results-via-caret-and-randomforest-package-using-seeds-on) on Stats.SE.

---

As a couple of answers on Stats.SE mention, `dat$pred_caret` differ from `dat$pred` because `predict.train` uses the whole training set, while with `predict.randomForest` we have that

> newdata   - a data frame or matrix containing new data. (Note: If not
>   given, **the out-of-bag prediction in object is returned.**

where `rf_gridsearch$finalModel$predicted` is basically the same as

```
randomForest:::predict.randomForest(rf_gridsearch$finalModel)
```

since `rf_gridsearch$finalModel` is an object of `randomForest` class. That is, no `newdata` gets provided.

As for the error, it relates to the fact that `train` and `randomForest` treat data differently. This time it's not about scaling or centering, but rather about creating dummies. In particular, `randomForest` is looking for the `C` variable (factor), while `train` created dummy variable `CB <- 1 * (C == "B")`. Hence, you may replicate the result of `predict.train` with

```
predict(object = rf_gridsearch$finalModel, 
        newdata = model.matrix(~ A + B + C, dat[, 2:4])[, -1])
```

where

```
model.matrix(~ A + B + C, dat[, 2:4])[, -1]
#     A    B CB
# 1 1.3 44.5  0
# 2 4.4 50.1  0
# 3 5.5 23.7  1
# 4 6.7 89.2  1
# 5 8.1 10.5  1
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. But I provided new data for the predict() function. So why does it return the OOB prediction?

Comment: @yPennylane, I clarified that in my answer, let me know if something is still unclear. You did indeed provide data in `dat$pred2`, but got an error. I explained the error; once we fix it, then it indeed isn't the OOB prediction anymore and coincides with `dat$pred`.

Comment: I also provided new data for computing `dat$pred` (`dat$pred <- predict(object = rf_gridsearch, newdata = dat[,2:4])`). That line didn't prouce an error, but gave different values than `rf_gridsearch$finalModel$predicted`

Comment: @yPennylane, 1) `rf_gridsearch` is of class `train` and uses `predict.train`, 2) `rf_gridsearch$finalModel` is of class `randomForest` and uses `predict.randomForest`, 3) due to what I said in my answer (and many linked answers discuss), `rf_gridsearch$finalModel$predicted` gives the same as `predict(rf_gridsearch$finalModel)` and that is OOB, 4) using `predict(rf_gridsearch)` with or without newdata gives not OOB, `predict(rf_gridsearch$finalModel, newdata = ...)` also would give not OOB.

Comment: ok. But what is it then, that `predict(rf_gridsearch)` gives? Does it predict values using all the input data (newdata) with the final model?

Comment: @yPennylane, yes, whenever we use `newdata` with any of the two objects, we specify the test data to predict, and the difference only appears how `predict.train` and `predict.randomForest` behave without `newdata`. The former, `predict(rf_gridsearch)`, indeed simply uses all the input data - training set (as `newdata`).